# Descifrar caligrafía de certificado de matrimonio

Tags: parentesco, genealogía, orígenes

Estoy haciendo mi árbol genealógico y he dado con mi ancestro [Cristóbal Gómez](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:N332-4L6), casado en Alborea, año 1624. El enlace muestra su certificado de matrimonio con Catalina Gómez:

[image]

Me interesa saber el nombre del padre de Catalina, que aparece en este cacho del certificado:

[image]

Por si resulta de ayuda, aquí intento transcribir la mayoría del certificado:

> Cristóbal Gómez / Catalina Gómez. En doce días de mayo de mill y seis cientos y veinte y quatro años yo Cristóbal Gonçález cura de este lugar de Alborea desposé por palabras de presente aviendo precedido las tres moniciones y todo lo demás necesario sigún y como lo manda el concilio de Trenti [Trento] a Cristóbal Gómez hijo de Pedro López y de Ana Gómez parroquianos de el lugar de Casas de Yvañes y a Catalina Gómes hija de **? de la Cuesta ?** y de María Granero parroquianos de esta parroquia y los velle siendo testigos presentes ? Pascual Pérez Valiente y Domingo Gómez Monteagudo y Jorge de Contreras y otros testigos y lo firmé...

En negrita está el nombre del padre de Catalina (me falta su nombre y su segundo apellido). El apellido de la Cuesta sé que es ese porque lo tienen los hijos de Catalina. A ver si podéis ayudarme, muchas gracias.

**Actualización:** El segundo apellido no es en realidad un apellido: es la palabra **diffunto**. Pero todavía sigo sin descifrar el nombre del padre de Catalina.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the Spanish language.

Answer (score 2):

¡Ya lo tengo! El nombre es *Hm<sup>o</sup>*, con *o* voladita. Como se indica en [esta página web](http://www.apellidositalianos.com.ar/abreviaturas-de-nombres-propios.html), *Hm<sup>o</sup>* es abreviatura de *Herónimo* o *Jerónimo*.

Comment: Compro compro. Yo iba a tirar Herminio pero me gusta más esta